# Fazer uma busca para meu site em duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, select

Estou precisando de fazer uma busca para meu site em que me retornassem primeiro as empresas que possuem algo semelhante ao digitado e, logo em baixo, mostrassem todos os produtos registrados com algo semelhante ao digitado.

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
tbl_empresas
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` longtext,
  `imagem` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

e

```
tbl_produtos
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` longtext,
  `aplicacao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagem` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo_original` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `tbl_categoria_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `tbl_empresa_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Tentei realizar uma pesquisa usando JOIN, porém ele me retornaria as duas tabelas juntas, dessa maneira não conseguiria separa o que é produto e o que é empresa na visualização da pesquisa.

Eu queria que minha pesquisa mostrassem primeiro as empresas, depois os produtos (sem relacionamento) e que fosse possível fazer uma paginação depois.

Isso seria possivel?
Se sim, como eu precisaria de fazer?

Comment: Fazer o select na tabela de empresa e depois usar o UNION com o select ta tabela de produtos te ajudaria?

Comment: eu não tinha tentado UNION, vou fazer um teste aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode unir o resultado de dois `selects` usando o `UNION ALL`

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT nome, descricao, 'empresa' AS tipo FROM tbl_empresas
where descricao like 'palavra%';

UNION ALL

SELECT nome, descricao, 'produto' AS tipo FROM tbl_produtos
WHERE descricao LIKE 'palavra%';
```

[Veja funcionando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e351b/2)

Comment: o select funcionou, porém eu consigo fazer a distinção dessas tabelas ao mostrar na visualização? ou ficaria tudo junto mesmo?

Comment: Pode fazer a distinção por uma coluna, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @Lucas funcionou?

Comment: esta quase funcionando, falta juntar com o where

Comment: Mas é só colocar o `where`, jovem. Editei a resposta

Comment: consegui fazer com where, porém tive um problema de "Undefined index: descricao" ao mostrar

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

select nome, descricao from (
  SELECT nome, descricao, 1 ordem FROM tbl_empresas
  where descricao like 'palavra%'
  UNION
  SELECT nome, descricao, 2 ordem FROM tbl_produtos
  WHERE descricao LIKE 'palavra%'
)
order by ordem;